# RabbitMQ ACCESS_REFUSED

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, queue

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ, it was working perfectly yesterday and works for my coworkers, but on my machine I am getting:

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:385) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0]
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1225) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0]
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0]
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1342) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectHostPort(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:638) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:603) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:550) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:686) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:257) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$RabbitResourceFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:345) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:102) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:85) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:613) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1378) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1223) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

The only difference from yesterday is I am having a lot of issues with STS 4.17.0, it has not been responding, something is making it spin out of control, so I created a new workspace and downloaded STS again in case it was corrupted (not sure if fixed).

I have tried wiresharking it, and can see the credentials are getting passed in.  The user has permissions and as specified was working fine yesterday and connects to rabbit for others.

Rabbit is running in a kubernetes stack on docker on my machine, I checked the logs and do not see anything there despite it saying check the broker logfile.

Any ideas?  I am completely out of ideas and has lost a whole day trying to get it to connect.

The code is written in Java for Spring Boot.

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectionFactories {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectionFactories.class);

@Autowired
private AmqpSettings settings;

@Autowired
private QueueSettings queueSettings;

private CachingConnectionFactory makeConnectionFactory(String host, int port, String username, String password,
        String virtualHost) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException,
        FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    RabbitConnectionFactoryBean rabbitCF = new RabbitConnectionFactoryBean();
    rabbitCF.setHost(host);
    rabbitCF.setPort(port);
    rabbitCF.setUsername(username);
    rabbitCF.setPassword(password);
    rabbitCF.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
    return new CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitCF.getRabbitConnectionFactory());
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = { "mule4RabbitCachingConnectionFactory" })
@DependsOn(value = {"amqpSettings"})
CachingConnectionFactory mule4RabbitCachingConnectionFactory() throws KeyManagementException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    logger.info("Configuring mule4 Rabbit caching connection factory");
    return makeConnectionFactory(settings.getHost(), settings.getPort(), settings.getUsername(),
            settings.getPassword(), queueSettings.getMule4VirtualHost());
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("mule4RabbitCachingConnectionFactory")
SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory mule4RabbitListenerContainerFactory(
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        @Qualifier("mule4RabbitCachingConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
        throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException,
        FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    logger.info("Configuring mule4 Rabbit listener factory");
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(20);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(20);
    factory.setMessageConverter(new QueueMessageConverter());
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(Boolean.FALSE);
    return factory;
}

}
```

The properties class.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("queue.rabbitmq")
@Component
public class AmqpSettings {
private String host;
private Integer port;
private String username;
private String password;

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}
public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}
public Integer getPort() {
    return port;
}
public void setPort(Integer port) {
    this.port = port;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

    
}
```

I also think there is a race condition loading the properties this way, it happens sometimes where I think the properties are not read before the connection is established.

Sorry, I know it's a lot, but really stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  So when I installed my docker instance of rabbit, there was a local version already installed, and they were both listening on the same port.  Somehow the installation overrode it so it was going to the docker version, but when I rebooted the next day the windows service turned on my local version so it was trying to send my user configured in the docker version to the local version instead.